# Pass Data to Controller from Table in View with C#/Razor MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a main view with multiple partial views in my C# MVC. The initial partial view contains a list which is populated from a model in a table. I want to be able to click a row on the table, and then populate another partial view based on the ID.

I have initially used: `<tr type="submit" onclick = "location.href = '@(Url.Action("RowClicked", "Test", new { id = @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID) }))'" >` which did pass the ID to the server, but it took me to a new page.

I am not sure if I need to use forms. I want to be able to click one of the rows to redraw another partial view based on the value of the ID in the row clicked without the whole page refreshing.

How do you send data using Razor/C# to the server in general without calling a new page, and how do I do this from each row of a table?

Thanks

Comment: You need to use ajax if you want to stay on the same page (and update the view in the success callback)

Comment: <tr type="submit" is the wrong usage.
You can use modal-popup or render a partial-view with in main view to display data.
To post a data to server either you can use ajax. or if you are using model based view you can use form.

Comment: *How do you send data using Razor/C# to the server in general without calling a new page* - This cannot be done.  You need to use **[AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)** to be able to send data to the server without a page refresh.

Answer (score 3):

Few hints you can follow :

**Option 1: Inherit from parent page**

By default, any partial view rendered by calling @Html.Partial("PartialViewName") will get the view model passed to the parent view.

So if you have:

```
View Model

namespace MyNamesapce
{
    public OrderInfoViewModel
    {
        public string OrderTitle { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

*OrderInfo.cshtml*

```
@model MyNamespace.OrderInfoViewModel

<h1>@Model.OrderTitle</h1>

@Html.Partial("OrderLineItems")
```

The OrderLineItems page should get a MyNamespace.OrderViewModel passed to it... so your partial view should look like this:

*OrderLineItems.cshtml*

```
@model MyNamespace.OrderInfoViewModel

foreach (var orderItem in Model.OrderItems)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

**Option 2: Specify model**

You can use the second parameter to specify the view model to be passed. I.e.

*OrderInfo.cshtml*

```
@model MyNamespace.OrderInfoViewModel

<h1>@Model.OrderTitle</h1>

@Html.Partial("OrderLineItems", Model.OrderItems)
```

*OrderLineItems.cshtml*

```
@model IEnumerable<OrderItem>

foreach (var orderItem in Model)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

***Option 3: Use partial actions***

If you need to reuse a partial view over multiple pages, it could be a good idea to use a partial view to eliminate having to populate different view models with the same info just because the page is going to be using the same partial.

E.g.

View Model

```
namespace MyNamesapce
{
    public OrderInfoViewModel
    {
        public string OrderTitle { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public class OrderController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult OrderInfo(int orderId)
    {
        OrderInfoViewModel viewModel = GetViewModel(orderId);
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    public PartialViewResult OrderLineItems(int orderId)
    {
        IEnumerable<OrderItem> orderItems = GetOrderItems(orderId);
        return Partial(orderItems);
    }
}
```

*OrderInfo.cshtml*

```
@model MyNamespace.OrderInfoViewModel

<h1>@Model.OrderTitle</h1>

@Html.Action("OrderLineItems")
```

*OrderLineItems.cshtml*

```
@model IEnumerable<OrderItem>

foreach (var orderItem in Model.OrderItems)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```